# Greedy number partitioning to minimize the maximum

Tags: partitioning, greedy

I have a list `l` with 4 * n numbers. I have another array `a` with n numbers. All of them are integers. I want to partition `l` into `n` subsets: `l1`,`l2`,...`ln`. I add the first number of `a` to `l1`, second number to `l2`, ... and last number to `ln`. Call the resultant subsets `l1_prime`,`l2_prime`,...`ln_prime`. How can I come up with an algorithm such that the maximum of these subsets is minimized?

For example, supposed I had `l = [1,2,3,4]` and `a = [5,6]`. I can create `l1_prime = [6,7]` and `l2_prime = [9,10]`. The maximum of these subsets would be 10. I want to come up with an algorithm to minimize this maximum. I know how to do this through brute force but I want to be more efficient.

I've looked into greedy number partitioning, but I can't find an answer. Can I please get some guidance on this question? I'm stuck.